# How do you plot $f(x)=x^2$ in the split-complex plane?

Tags: graphing-functions, split-complex-numbers

> What does the graph of $f(x)=x^2$ look like in the split-complex plane? How do you plot it?

for split-complex number $x.$

So, I think you have to do $f(a+bj)=(a+bj)^2=a^2+2abj+b^2j^2$

$j^2=+1$ in this case, as opposed to $j^2=-1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [online plotting tool](https://people.ucsc.edu/%7Ewbolden/complex/#z%5E2) you can change between the complex plane and the split-complex plane by choosing between $i^2 = -1$ and $i^2 = 1$.

Comment: It seems to say that access is forbidden now, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20221002141349/https://people.ucsc.edu/~wbolden/complex/#z) is the last working archive.